# Можно ли программно перезагрузить отдельную видеокарту на Linux?

Tags: linux, radeon

Есть машина, к которой подключено n-ное количество видеокарт. Проблема в том, что периодически некоторые из них зависают, и машину приходится перезагружать. Есть ли предусмотренная линуксом функция, позволяющая перезагрузить видеокарту выполнением команды в консоли, или еще как-нибудь?

Карточки  GygaByte Radeon 470

Comment: Смотрите в исходники драйвера... Ах, у вас не Интел? Тогда ой.

Comment: @0andriy, обновил вопрос

Comment: можно питание дернуть программно (сон, режим ожидания), но проснуться ли они?

Comment: @eri, вопрос больше не актуален, так что не могу сказать :)